# Who am I? I rhymes with flow

Tags: riddle, rhyme

My first puzzle! and also an entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/fortnightly-topic-challenge-41-short-and-sweet)

> I am short but not in sorrow
>   Yesterday I went but I still have tomorrow
>   As long as people use me like a pro
>
> You call me in a race, at the beginning of the show
>   Because, I am just a game for people who know
>   Who am I? I rhymes with flow

I hope you like it :)

Comment: Where is the entry? I can't see it on the list. Just reminding, thx

Comment: ouch sorry :)  I think it will automatically be listed, thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you

> Go?

I am short but not in sorrow

> The word GO is short

Yesterday I went but I still have tomorrow

> The past tense of GO is went, but you can GO tomorrow

As long as people use me like a pro

> GoPro cameras (thanks to @jafe!)

You call me in a race, at the beginning of the show

> Ready, set, GO.  It's GO time!

Because, I am just a game for people who know

> GO is a game

Who am I? I rhymes with flow

> GO rhymes with flow

Comment: I think the pro line might refer to a certain camera manufacturer?

Comment: It's correct! You even managed to answer every hint correctly! I believe it will be easy for this community ;)

Comment: @all this is my first puzzle, I am open to suggestions :)

Answer (score 3):

> Bow?

I am short but not in sorrow

> Front part: the word is short in length

Yesterday I went but I still have tomorrow

> Bow is an ancient weapon, but not totally eliminated nowadays

As long as people use me like a pro

> As long as people shoot professionally with accuracy, it is a pretty good weapon

You call me in a race, at the beginning of the show

> One bows at the beginning of a performance/ show

Because, I am just a game for people who know

> Perhaps referring to Katniss Everdeen in Hunger Games, who uses a bow?

Who am I? I rhymes with flow

> Bow rhymes with flow

Comment: +1 This answer is so good, but sorry this is not the intended answer ;)

Comment: Never mind, enjoyed it though, +1

Answer (score 2):

I am short but not in sorrow

> Time. It feels like time is short (running fast) when one is happy, but not so when one is in sorrow

Yesterday I went but I still have tomorrow

> Time has past (gone) yesterday but will come (again) tomorrow

As long as people use me like a pro

> And that's especially for people who know how to use time (plan for future and not worry over the past)

You call me in a race, at the beginning of the show

> Typically races are *timed*

Because, I am just a game for people who know

> Most of the times, it's about who did it on time (usually first)

Who am I? I rhymes with flow

> Time rhymes with tide (as in *time and tide wait for none*) and tide is synonymous with (tidal) flow

Comment: Sorry but this is not the intended answer ;)